# Java: Image Loader Library (JPG, PNG, GIF, TIFF, TGA)

Tags: java, image, loader

Advise me an image loader library which could load such formats as JPG, PNG, TIFF, TGA.
It would be great if It could say me a pixel formats, such as R8G8B8, R5G6B5,..

Comment: Where are you loading the images from?

Comment: If you want more people to answer your questions, you should start to accept more answers to your questions.  You have 9 with 0 accepted right now.

Comment: @Piyush I am loading image from file.

Comment: ImageMagick and it's JImageMagick wrapper.  JAI and the default ImageIO jokes are kindergarden stuff compared to *ImageMagick*.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage is a pretty common one that is used.  Check out the docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).  If you want something that wraps the entire process, look at [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).  Use the

> public static BufferedImage read(File
>   input)

method.

Comment: I need loading from file. And this loading must be independent on the file format. I give file, loader gives me pixels.

Comment: Try using ImageIO then.  I've updated the answer above with the link.